# Protractor tests slowing down when runtime increases

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I currently have a set of protractor tests in one suite that require about 45 minutes to 1 hours to complete. As the tests progress, I notice a severe increase in run time per test.

The following code are the tests I'm executing in my spec.js file:

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
    (function(test){

        it('Should load the team page', function(){
            teamPage.loadTeamPage();
        });
        it('Should create a credential with a team', function(){
            teamPage.createCredentialWithTeam(test, 'Test Team');
        });
        it('Should create a schedule with a team', function(){
            teamPage.createScheduleWithTeam(test, 'Test Team');
        });
        it('Should create a task with a team', function(){
            teamPage.createTaskWithTeam(test, 'Test Team');
        });
        it('Should edit a team', function(){
            teamPage.editTeamByName(test, 'Test Team', 'New Test Team','Testing Department', true);
        });
        it('Should add a team member', function(){
            teamPage.addTeamMember(test, 'Test Team', 'foo', 'Admin', true);
        });
        it('Should load the department page', function(){
            departmentPage.loadDepartmentPage();
        });
        it('Should edit a department', function(){
            departmentPage.editDepartmentByName(test, 'Testing Department', 'Testing Department Edited', 'non', true);
        });
        it('Should view a department', function(){
            departmentPage.viewDepartmentByName('Testing Department')
        });
        it('Should add a departmentmember', function(){
            departmentPage.addDepartmentMember(test, 'Testing Department', 'foo', 'Admin', true);
        });
        it('Should load the organisation page', function(){
            organisationPage.loadOrganisationPage();
        });
        it('Should add a department', function(){
            organisationPage.addDepartment(test, 'Test Department Protractor', 'Test Case Organisation', true, true);
        });
        it('Should attempt to add members to an organisation', function(){
            organisationPage.addOrganisationMember(test, 'Test Case Organisation', 'foo', 'Admin', true);
        });
        it('Should check the organisation and compare the details with the view page', function(){
            organisationPage.viewOrganisationByName('Test Case Organisation');
        });
        it('Should try to edit an organisations details', function(){
            organisationPage.editOrganisation(test, 'Test Case Organisation', 'Edited Test Case Organisation');
        });
        it('Should log out', function(){
            HomePage.logout();
        });
    })(users[i]);
}
```

I'm not sure if this is bad practice to write all of this inside a for-loop but I can't imagine if that has anything to do with the drop in performance. Starting out, every test within the for-loop takes about 15-20 seconds. When testing the entire loop, I've encountered spec time-outs which forced me into adding the following code into my conf.js:

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000}
```

This increases the default time out value of 30000(ms) to 60000(ms). The speed at which protractor interacts with the browser is also visually decreasing.
I've read about starting a new instance of WebDriver before each test but this seems like an overall increase in runtime.

EDIT: The following also crossed my mind: I have a html-screenshot-reporter for jasmine2 attached to this process which captures a screenshot after every test, is it possible that it caches every single one of these images and that this accumulates with the tests itself to put some strain on the host system?

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with protractor?
Any input is appreciate. If you require more information, don't hesitate to ask.

Cheers

Comment: You can try running node with `--expose-gc` to see if the underlying node process is spending a lot of time in GC.  That would either mean (1) you're creating too much garbage or (2) the heap is running low (and its trying hard to scrape up some space all the time).

Comment: Thanks @P.T. for your reply. Against what app would I run this command? Protractor itself, conf.js, the current spec.js? I've tried all of these to no avail.

Comment: You'll need to pass it on the node command line: `node --expose-gc ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor <rest of protractor options>`, I think.